# How to change a value capture from the glade file?

Tags: gtk, glade

After I design the GUI with glade,I want to write some code about,for example I want to change the value of a label in the glade,how can I do this ?Which function can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference ([gtk_builder_get_object](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkBuilder.html)) these within the code and then you can use the standard set of API calls on them (so this depends on your widget type).